# What's the meaning of Txn factor?

Tags: ucsc, transcription-factors, transcriptome-regulation

The transcription factor track in UCSC is named as Txn factor. Why Txn == Transcription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any other abbreviation is likely to work for "translation" as well and the x makes it sound a bit like transcription (txn would be pronounced something like "tixon").

Comment: I'm guessing `tx` came into existence first, and `tx` is closer to "transcripts".